# jQuery plugin - colorbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, colorbox

I am trying to use colorbox jQuery plugin to display an image in a new window in asp.net mvc 3.

I tried creating a click able image which didn't work

I dont know where to start with this even though I thought that I did- I have edited the "_Layout.cshtml" page to include the jQuery colorbox plugin but I am not sure why it is not working.

below is the code for the jQuery

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/colorbox.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/colorbox-1.4.15.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#main').find('.content .gallery .gal').colorbox({
                'rel' : 'gal',
                'maxHeight' : '90%',
                'scrolling' : false,
                'scalePhotos' : true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

below is an example a tag

```
 <a href="../../Content/themes/base/images/dumb.jpg" class="gal" />
```

Any Help with this matter would be gratefully received.

Comment: I have now fixed this but I would still welcome any comment/ discussion on the topic.

Comment: Try using `jQuery(window).load(function () {` instead of JQuery DOM function